# Polar plane spiral repitions

Tags: self-learning, polar-coordinates

I'm just starting out teaching my self about the polar plane using tools like [Desmos](http://desmos.com) and have been wondering:

> When graphing an equation in the polar plane, does it extend forever?

All the tools I've used repeat a spiral finitely, but the number of repetitions changes. Is it actually infinite and computing limitations are the limiting factor here?

Comment: If you're talking about a spiral like $r=a+b\theta$ for $a, b \in \Bbb R$, then yes, the spiral extends outward toward infinity.

Comment: On a side note, I like [this graph of a spiral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r%3D1%2B2*theta+from+0+%3C+theta+%3C+1000).  It looks like a long blue tunnel.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gotit--thanks ! That makes much more sense now!

Comment: @gotit--thanks Could you please convert your comment into an answer so this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" queue? I don't think there's a whole lot more to say than what you've said, and the fact that this question has gone unanswered for over three years supports that theory.